# Why is this object not an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not a Javascript person, but have inherited the joys. So far so good.

My javascript object, in firebug, looks like this

[image]

This shows that the array `sss` has 4 items in the array (0,1,2 and 3).

The complication comes when I expand one of these elements, I see

[image]

From my own tests these are `not` arrays. They are just treated as objects (or so it seems).

Within each DataItem, there is an object, you can just make it out called lzabel. Each DataItem has this value. I need to read the values within a for loop.

So, I would have hoped to use

```
for (var i = 0; i < sss[0];i++)
{
    var z = sss[0][i]; //This is never executed
}
```

but no! No error, but the loop's content is never executed (as if sss[0] has no items).

How do I loop through like this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < sss[0];i++)
{
    var z = sss[0][i]["lzabel"];
}
```

**EDIT**

I added the following code

```
var t1 = sss.length;
var t2 = sss[0].length;
```

Firebug reports `t1 = 4`, and t2 as undefined.

Comment: Loop over the object's properties?

Comment: "Due to signing various non-disclosure agreements" - irrelevant. we don't need the *actual* code. any minimal code which *reproduces the problem* does the job.

Comment: Actually, I was talking about the screen shots being cut in such a way, and my comment was only to be polite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Izabel ...

```
var sssData = sss[0];   // FYI: sss[0].length won't work because it's an object not an array

for (x in sssData) {
    var dataItem = sssData[x];
    console.log( dataItem.Izabel );    // one way to get Izabel property value
    console.log( dataItem["Izabel"] )  // two ways to get Izabel property value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop like this:

```
for (i in sss[0]) {
    var z = sss[0][i];
}
```

Comment: `i` is undefined (although it does now execute in the loop)!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for(i=0;i<sss.length;i++){
 for(j=1;j<parseInt(Object.keys(sss[i]).length)+1;j++){
     console.log(sss[i]["DataItem"+j].Izabel);
  }
 }
```